# How to check exact memory usage of node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory

I develope `node js` with `mongodb` application on windows. For memory check, I usually use windows task manager, but it is not an good option, I think.

How to check exact memory usage of `mongodb` queries? I can `aggregate` all needed data  in one query, but maybe 2 `projection` will be better option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple one line code using `Object.entries()` and adjust to readable format

```
Object.entries(process.memoryUsage()).forEach(item => console.log(`${item[0]}: ${(item[1] / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(4)} MB`))
```

output:

```
rss: 70.7695 MB
heapTotal: 85.4063 MB
heapUsed: 55.2614 MB
external: 0.0794 MB
```